# JSLint on Visual Studio/ASP.NET MVC Projects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jslint

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the [JsLint plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd).

Is there a better way to use JsLint for inline javascript in CSHTML files?

- If I try to select the javascript text and run the tools just on the selection I get a bunch of errors related to spacing (e.g. "var should be on column 13, not 9"). This happens because the IDE indents the javascript code inside the `<script>`tags.
- I get errors on variables that are rendered from razor code like this: `result = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));`

I currently just copy the code onto an empty .js file and run the tool from there, but it's kinda of nuisance to be switching.

What would be the best configuration (or alternate plugin) to work easier with jsLint validation on this scenario?

Comment: What's the error on `result = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper is the best tool I've used for javascript coding.  It works very well and highlights the majority of the issues that you'd be looking for with JsLint, though it's not nearly as comprehensive of course.

On the other hand, I'd be concerned about the amount of javascript you're writing in a view.  If you have that much, perhaps you should consider moving it out of your views into standalone files.

Comment: It's not that much code, it's just a nuisance copy/pasting the JS onto another file in order to validate.

Comment: @amhed Ah, fair enough.  It was impossible to tell.  Either way, Resharper speeds up my javascript development considerably.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to open up the options pane.  I'm using the VS.2010 version, but my Tools >>> JSLint Options menu option opens up the following settings pane:

[image]

You're running into JSLint without the [`white` option set to true](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).

You might want to steal some of the other settings I've got above to remove some of the more draconian rules.  The above works very well for me.  ;^)